# Compute raster math in QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins

I'm writing a QGIS plugin and I need to create a raster layer as the average of other rasters. How can I do it? I have tried to use `gdal_calc.py` through `os.system`, something like:

```
cmd = 'gdal_calc.py 
       -A first_layer.tif 
       -B second_layer.tif 
       --outfile=AVG.tif 
       --cal="(A+B)/2"'
os.system(cmd)
```

but it seems that the command (which works perfectly fine in the command line) is not executed from my QGIS plugin. What should I use to create my average raster?

---

I finally found a solution, and I share it for those who might be interested:

```
from gdal_calculations import Dataset, Env


def aggregate_layers(self, layers):
    datasets = []
    for l in layers:
        datasets.append(Dataset(l))
    sum = datasets[0]
    for i in range(1, len(datasets) - 1):
        sum += datasets[i]
    Env.overwrite = True
    avg = sum
    avg /= len(datasets)
    root = '/home/kalimaha'
    file_name = root + '/average.tif'
    avg.save(file_name)
    if self.dlg.open_in_qgis.isChecked() is True:
        rl = self.iface.addRasterLayer(file_name, 'Average Layer')
```

---

I have tried @xunilk's code, but my QGIS simply crashes. I had to edit it a bit, this is the final code:

```
def aggregate_layers(self, layers):

    entries = []
    for l in layers:
        fileInfo = QFileInfo(l)
        baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
        rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(l, baseName)
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('rlayer: ' + str(rlayer), 'Geobricks TRMM')
        layer = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        layer.ref = rlayer.name() +'@1'
        layer.raster = rlayer
        layer.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(layer)

    for e in entries:
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('e: ' + str(e), 'Geobricks TRMM')

    fileInfo = QFileInfo(layers[0])
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(layers[0], baseName)
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('rlayer: ' + str(rlayer), 'Geobricks TRMM')

    expression = '(' + entries[1].ref + ' + ' + entries[0].ref + ') / 2'
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Expression: ' + str(expression), 'Geobricks TRMM')
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression,
                               '/Development/GIS/average.tif',
                               'GTiff',
                               rlayer.extent(),
                               rlayer.width(),
                               rlayer.height(),
                               entries)
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('calc: ' + str(calc), 'Geobricks TRMM')
```

My layers are not in QGIS yet, so I have to load it from the filesystem, the array nemd `layers` contains the absolute paths of the layers I need to aggregate. So, when I do `calc = QgsRasterCalculator(...` QGIS crashes.

Comment: Try putting python or python.exe in front of your gdal_calc.py or use a full path.  Those might help.

Comment: This solution may work on my machine, but it is not OS portable.

Comment: @Kalimaha 3 You need a **path** and back slash as separator at **cmd** expression. Please, see my edited answer. It works.

Comment: @xunilk I will try your first solution (and many thanks for it), but not the edit, to avoid the use of `os.system` which I don't find very elegant.

Comment: @Kalimaha  Ok. My first solution really works. I have used it in my own plugins.

Comment: Your solution should be cut/pasted into an answer. Self-answering is permitted and encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing a QGIS plugin you can use **QgsRasterCalculator** and **QgsRasterCalculatorEntry** classes. For example, this code works well at Python Console (and it could be adapted perfectly for your plugin as a function):

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import  iface
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

mc = iface.mapCanvas()

Layers = mc.layers()

entries = []

for lyr in Layers:
    # Define bands
    layer = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    layer.ref = lyr.name() +'@1'
    layer.raster = lyr
    layer.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append( layer )

root = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/'

expression = '(  ' + entries[1].ref + '   +  '  + entries[0].ref + '  ) / 2 '

print expression

calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression, 
                            root + 'average.tif', 
                            'GTiff', 
                            Layers[0].extent(), 
                            Layers[0].width(), 
                            Layers[0].height(), 
                            entries )

calc.processCalculation()
```

I tried it out with two raster (**b3_ref** and **b4_ref**); as it can see at the next image. After running the code, the resulting raster was named as **average.tif**. I corroborated, with the Value Tool Plugin, that its values were as expected. At the Python Console was also printed the calculation expression for purposes of verification.

[image]

**Editing Note 1:**

By using **gdal_calc.py**, next code works well in the Python Console (path is in Unix notation and the slash, '\', it is necessary at **cmd** expression).

```
import os

root_path = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/'

cmd = "gdal_calc.py -A " + \
      root_path + \
      "b3_ref.tif -B " + \
      root_path + \
      "b4_ref.tif --outfile=" + \
      root_path + \
      "AVG.tif --cal='(A+B)/2'"

os.system(cmd)
```

**Editing Note 2:**

Debugged code. It works in my Python Console. Wrong or unnecessary lines were commented.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

def average_layers(layers):   #I changed the name
                              #I eliminated "self" to avoid create a plugin

    entries = []

    for l in layers:
#        fileInfo = QFileInfo(l) #external function
#        baseName = fileInfo.baseName() #external function
        layer = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
#        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('rlayer: ' + str(rlayer), 'Geobricks TRMM')
        layer = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
        layer.ref = l.name() +'@1'
        layer.raster = l
        layer.bandNumber = 1
        entries.append(layer)

#    for e in entries:
#        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('e: ' + str(e), 'Geobricks TRMM')
#
#    fileInfo = QFileInfo(layers[0]) #external function
#    baseName = fileInfo.baseName() #external function
#    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(layers[0], baseName) #external function
#    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('rlayer: ' + str(rlayer), 'Geobricks TRMM')

    expression = '(' + entries[1].ref + ' + ' + entries[0].ref + ') / 2'
#    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Expression: ' + str(expression), 'Geobricks TRMM')
    calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression,
                               '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/average.tif', #my absolute pass
                               'GTiff',
                               layers[0].extent(),
                               layers[0].width(),
                               layers[0].height(),
                               entries)

    calc.processCalculation()
#    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('calc: ' + str(calc), 'Geobricks TRMM')

mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas() 

layers = mapcanvas.layers() #it has the references to the layers
                            #you don't need fileInfo or baseName

average_layers(layers)
```